# Zscore in Python and Matlab have different result

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, statistics

here is the code in python

```
x = np.array( [ [1, 10, 4], [3, 2, 1], [5, 1, 0] ] , dtype = np.float128 );
x = zscore(x, axis = 0);
print x;
```

the output is

```
[[-1.2247449  1.40693  1.3728129]
[ 0.0 -0.57932412 -0.39223227]
[ 1.2247449 -0.82760589 -0.98058068]]
```

In matlab,

```
xxx = [1 10 4 ; 3 2 1; 5 1 0]
zscore(xxx)
```

output is

```
-1.0000    1.1488    1.1209
0   -0.4730   -0.3203
1.0000   -0.6757   -0.8006
```

why sciPy.stats.zscore and matlab zscore function are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab's computation is equivalent to SciPy's with `ddof=1`. SciPy defaults to `ddof=0`.

Comment: @Joe if it is the answer, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) to indicate that the problem is solved.